# Как добавить пустой элемент в список?

Tags: cmake

Есть CMake скрипт:

```
unset(FOO)
list(APPEND FOO "")
list(APPEND FOO "")
list(APPEND FOO "")
list(APPEND FOO "")
list(LENGTH FOO SIZE)
message(FATAL_ERROR ${SIZE})
```

Ожидание - 4. Ральность - 0.

Я нашел обходной путь, но он выгдлядит как костыль:

```
set(FOO "dummy")
set(FOO "${FOO};")
set(FOO "${FOO};")
set(FOO "${FOO};")
set(FOO "${FOO};")
list(REMOVE_AT FOO 0)
message(FATAL_ERROR ${SIZE})
```

Пример несколько проще чем то, что я делаю на самом деле, так что не предлагайте написать `set(FOO ";;;")`:) Элементы приходят извне в неизвестном количестве, и пустые из них только некоторые. Вроде такого:

```
function(do_smth LIST_WITH_EMPTY_ITEMS)
    unset(RESULT)
    foreach(X IN LISTS LIST_WITH_EMPTY_ITEMS)
        if(${CONDITION})
            list(APPEND RESULT "${X}")
        endif()
    endforeach()
endfunction()
```

Comment: А почему бы не условиться на некотором элементе, что он будет пустым? Зачем Вам именно пустота?

Comment: @ixSci, я хочу создать функцию, которая возвращает каждый n-й элемент. `nth_items("1;2;3;4;5;6;7" 1 3 RESULT) #RESULT = 1;4;7`. И я не хочу "проглатывать" пустые элементы

Comment: Просто вполне возможно, что добавить пустой элемент в CMake не получится, потому что список в CMake это, в сущности, строка. Поэтому понятия пустой элемент не совсем к нему применимы. Остаются костыли только, типа того, что у Вас в вопросе или того, что я написал.